# Convert pixel point to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to create a custom map for iOS. For the time being I am using Openstreetmap images for the custom map app.

Now what I want is to convert the pixel point to Latitude and Longitude value at a particular zoom level. I am finding out the tile(pixel point) in which I clicked. I need to find out the Lat and Long of that particular point. How this can be calculated? Is there any general formula to find the Lat & Long from pixel point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about route-me (https://github.com/route-me/route-me)? It is an open source iOS map library. I use a fork of this library found at https://github.com/Alpstein/route-me. These libraries provide the projections you are looking for and might even provide other functionalities you would have to implement yourself otherwise.

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for your reply. I downloaded and tried to run the project, but the project downloaded is full of bugs. Even without making any changes, the project is full of errors.

Comment: Besides the bugs that are reported in open issues I am not aware of any bugs. If you have any specific problems it is probably best if you either ask at the route-me google group http://groups.google.com/group/route-me-map or fill out an issue.